# How to customize the default CursorSize in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I set he default CursorSize in $PROFILE file like:

```
[Console]::CursorSize = 10
```

or

```
$HOST.UI.RawUI.CursorSize = 10
```

But the cursorSize will reset after using another console in powershell, for example:
[image]

Also, I set **CursorSize** from the **Registy Editor**:
[image]
and
[image]

Is there any way to change the default CursorSize permanently?

Answer (score 1):

1, try put your customization codes into file $profile.CurrentUserAllHosts instead and see if it applies to the python shell.

2, if it doesn't work, put your codes within the function prompt so that the codes will be forced to be invoked every time the prompt is printed.

Answer (score 0):

Well i hope this urls help you

[Modifying Your Windows PowerShell Profile](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156814.aspx#EBAA)

[Customizing the Console](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156814.aspx#EDAA)

Comment: I mean that, the CursorSize will be reset after run python. I know how to configure it